# Insert variable into function and solve for another variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following production function:

$$y=x_1^{0.4}\cdot x_2^{0.4}$$

and I know that $x_1 = \dfrac{x_2}2$.

I need to plug $x_1$ into the production function and solve it for $x_2$.

I've tried it this way:

$$y = \left(\dfrac{x_2}2\right)^{0.4}\cdot x_2^{0.4}$$

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how I can solve this for $x_2$.

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: I would start by simplifying the expression.
$$
\left(\frac{x_2}{2}\right)^{0.4} x_2^{0.4} = \frac{x_2^{0.4 + 0.4}}{2^{0.4}}= \frac{x_2^{0.8}}{2^{0.4}}
$$

Comment: Is $y$ known? If not, you cannot calculate $x_2$...

Comment: @5xum y isn't known. That's why I need to calculate x2(y)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming everything is positive

$$y = \left(\dfrac{x_2}2\right)^{0.4}\cdot x_2^{0.4}$$

$$y = \left(\dfrac{x_2^2}2\right)^{0.4}$$

$$y^{2.5} = \dfrac{x_2^2}2$$

$$2 y^{2.5} = x_2^2 $$

$$\sqrt{2} y^{1.25} = x_2 $$

Answer (score -1):

Hint: I would simplify your expression by replacing an awkward term like $x_1^{0.4}$ by the term $\sqrt[5]{x_1^2}$. Now you can proceed by using more algebraic techniques.

Comment: That is merely a simplification. It does not help to find either $x_1$ or $x_2$.

Comment: I disagree. As I understand the question, he is searching for a way of obtaining an equation of the form $x_2=f(y)$ for some function $f$ in terms of $y$. The hint would help in that regard.

Comment: Now that the OP has clarified that in the comment, it makes sense.